# How to get <div> Tag Attribute Using DOMXpath

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

Link = https://www.joemyerstoyota.com/new-inventory/index.htm

My code:

```
$websiteUrl = 'https://www.joemyerstoyota.com/new-inventory/index.htm';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $websiteUrl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $websiteUrl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$str = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$html_base = new simple_html_dom();
$html_base->load($str, TRUE, FALSE);

$mydata = array();

foreach($html_base->find('div.hproduct auto toyota') as $key => $element) 
{
    $mydata = $element->attr;
}

print_r($mydata);
```

It showing blank output. Can anyone help ?

Comment: A *multi class selector* needs multiple dots, e.g. `div.hproduct.auto.toyota`

Comment: $html_base->find('div.hproduct.auto.toyota')
i tried above syntax but still it showing blank array.

Comment: My guess would be that the site populates it's content via javascript. Which means curl only receives the *pre-rendered* output.

Comment: https://www.joemyerstoyota.com/new-inventory/index.htm

Can you look to this site and find "div.hproduct auto toyota". Its a huge help from you. Thanks.

The Div I Want to get it's in UL>LI>Div. So I Tried //ul[@class="class_name"]/li/div. But It's Still Not showing data. Please Help

Comment: I checked the site, and as guessed, it basically consists solely of script tags. Which means the elements you want to *scrape* are not present when you request the site's content via curl. You would need to **run** the scripts to get the final html. Ultimately this means that php is probably not the correct tool for this task. A first pick from google yields [this article](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/scrapping-the-content-of-single-page-application-spa-with-headless-chrome-and-puppeteer-d040025f752b) as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks. I Will Definitely Try This and Let You Know. Thanks Again